# how to save/use dom elements in an array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to store multiple DOM elements into an array, and then later use the array to put specific elements into the HTML Document. However, I haven't found a way that works... I've tried .innerHTML to store in the array and insertAdjacentHTML instead of appendChild but it doesn't work.

This is what I'm trying to do, but it doesn't work. Any other solutions/methods to achieve this?

```js
const arr = [];
const test = document.querySelector('.one');
arr[0] = test;

document.querySelector('.three').appendChild(arr[0])
```

```css
/* Styles for visual feedback only */
div[class] {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  position: relative;
  padding: 1rem .2rem .2rem;
}
div[class]:before {
  content: attr(class);
  position: absolute;
  top: .1rem;
  font-size: .8rem;
  color: #999;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <div class="two">
    <p> Test </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="three">

</div>
```

Comment: As written, your code currently is erroring with a different error message: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Missing initializer in const declaration`. If we fix that by changing the first line to `let arr = [];`, the code works properly. As such, this issue is not reproducible.

Comment: I wrote it quickly just to illustrate my point, but I'll edit it to make it more clear, sorry.

Comment: Your code works as expected (I turned it into a runnable snippet in your question)

Comment: hmmm, i can't seem to replicate it in my project...

Comment: When / where does your JS code run in relation to the rest of the document? Ie, where is your `<script>` tag?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14028959/283366)

Comment: I have it so its <script src = ___ defer> </script>

Comment: I'll do a bit more testing, thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

A `const` is not mutable use a `var` or a `let` to define your mutable variables.

```
var arr = [];
arr.push(document.querySelector('.one'));
```

Comment: A `const` cannot be redefined or redeclared. Objects declared as `const` are still mutable